# Solving the exponential equation $2e^x (x-1)=0$

Tags: logarithms

How does one solve the equation $2e^x (x-1)=0$ ?

Comment: Is that $2(x-1)e^x = 0$ or $2e^{x(x-1)} = 0$? Or something else?

Answer (score 10):

If $y$ and $z$ are Real (Complex) numbers, then $yz = 0$ exactly when at least one of $y = 0$ or $z = 0$.  Since $x \mapsto 2e^x$ and $x \mapsto x-1$ both are maps from Real numbers to Real numbers, $2e^x(x-1) = 0$ will be true exactly when at least one of the following is true:

(1) $2e^x = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $2 = 0$ or $e^x = 0$ (both impossible)

(2) $x - 1 = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x = 1$

so your only solution is $x = 1$.

Note that this is the same reason we factor the quadratic polynomial in the equation $ax^2 + bx +c = 0$, mainly so that we can break up the equation into two linear ones that are easily solved.

Also since I've seen this done before, $yz = r$ does **NOT necessarily** mean that either $y = r$ or $z = r$ when $r \neq 0$.  The reason $0$ holds a special place here is because if say $y \neq 0$, then we may multiply both sides by $1/y$ to get $z = r/y$, which is of course $0$ exactly when $r = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^x$ is always positive. So if your equation is $e^{x(x-1)} = 0$ then it has no solution. (Not over the reals, that is.)

Comment: Even over complex numbers, $e^z$ is never zero.

Comment: Good point actually. I love that function.